# Como localizar pelo windows uma string em um arquivo do Crystal Reports

Tags: windows, crystal-reports

Situação básica :

Os relatórios Crystal Reports de um diretório usam em alguns casos Stored Procedures como a Fonte de Dados, se tento localizar uma Stored Procedure que exista digamos "My_procedure" pelo Localizar do Windows no dito diretório não me retorna nada , já fiz o teste sabendo com certeza que um arquivo ao menos tinha esta referência.

Alguém sabe o caminho para fazer com que esta pesquisa funcione ?

Comment: A busca do windows é interpretada, ou seja, utilizando os interpretadores embutidos no sistema operacional (que podem não ser tão completos) ele faz a busca, não é uma busca em binário no arquivo. Talvez você precise de uma ferramenta de terceiro ou implementar seu próprio buscador binário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em termos de ferramentas eu utilizo há décadas para pesquisas mais complexas ou o www.xyplorer.com ou ainda o www.ztree.com.

O *Windows* fica a dever um comando robusto de consultas nos conteúdos de seus arquivos em linha de comando (DOS), bem como na *interface* gráfica.

O MS-DOS (cmd.com) não era nem para existir no *core* do *Windows*. Ele (MS-DOS) é fraco, lento e mal construído desde o Windows 95.

O único lugar em que ele (DOS) funciona bem é na linha *server*, sem a parte gráfica.

Comment: $$ é um problema. :)

Comment: instalei o ztree mas não consegui usar um "find" ou "search"

Answer (score 1):

Use a busca do Notepad++.

Por incrível que pareça, a busca do Windows no 7 em diante não é mais uma busca simples que olha dentro dos arquivos.
Pra fazer isso você precisa passar parâmetros, é muito ruim. Esquece e usa outra solução

Comment: Só um detalhe, eu uso o grep! Heheh em conjunto com o Cygwin

Comment: Valeu pela atenção, só uma questão , tenho de abrir um a um !? []s

Comment: @Motta existe um recurso de busca por arquivos dentro do programa. Você aponta uma pasta e ele localiza o interior dos arquivos todos dentro das pastas e das subpastas.

Comment: Valeu , vou tentar amanhã!

Comment: A busca do NotePad++ nõ funciona , creio que o CR faça alguma coisa que oculte a string ao gravar o arquivo, mas de qualquer forma a dica deste search já é valiosa.

Comment: Faz tempo que não trabalhava com Crystal. o SSRS trabalha com arquivos .xml, pensei que seria parecido. No site em ingles (o SO) encontrei algumas repostas dizendo que há software comerciais para isso, mas não são baratos.. e não funcionam com as versões mais recentes. Não sei se consigo te ajudar além disso. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313625/anyway-to-search-inside-a-crystal-report

Answer (score 1):

Esqueça as ferramentas de pesquisa built-in do Windows. É uma area onde a Microsoft tem de melhorar muito ainda.
Recomendo usar a ferramenta free [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack)
Ela permite pesquisa simples por nomes ou por conteúdo. Também permite usar expressões regulares. Usamos em nosso ambiente de produção a longo tempo.
Uma observação importante: a ferramenta só vai acessar os caminhos que o acesso forem permitidos.
Dica: use separador sentenças ponto-e-virgula para multiplas strings ou multiplos caminhos para as pesquisas.

Comment: Reconendo também o Agente Ransack